# runOnUiThread and lags

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a fragment that incorporates a ViewPager with custom views and a spinner in a top bar. Every time a change the page in the viewpager, I have to update strings in the spinner from a db. To do this, in the onPageSelected of the viewPager listener I launch a thread that retrieve data from the db and updates via runOnUiThread the spinner's adapter. The problem is that the notifyDataSetChanged() called for the spinner's adapter lags the viewpager: it has to rebuild few views, but it lags it a bit.

```
            @Override
        public void onPageSelected(final int pos) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
```

...

```
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mSpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

How to resolve this? It is possible to run code on the main thread with lowest priority?

Comment: I don't know if it's going to fix your problem or not but why don't you try using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of a thread and calling runOnUiThread()?

Comment: i don't understand why you have a thread calling runOnUiThread. Why don't you call notifyDataSetChanged directly? onPageSelected seems to indicate you are on the uithread already (and if not, you still don't need a thread for that)

Comment: Ok, i was unclear: I call a new Thread because i need to get data from the db and i don't want to lag the main thread. The (...) is the code in which i get data from the db. So I create a new thread, updates data and than come back in the main thread with the runOnUiThread to update UI.

But the problem is not that. The problem is the notifyDataSetChanged lags the main thread, so the scroll on the ViewPager is a bit laggy. If I comment the notifyDataSetChanged, the scroll is fluid.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the Thread, then try to remove the runOnUiThread.

Comment: Tried both: it remains fluid only if I don't run the notify. But, of course, i want to update it!

Comment: not entirely sure the notify must be on uithread. did you try to call it directly in the thread (also, if it lags, it could be because of what you do for updating the views)

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to get away with :

```
       @Override
    public void onPageSelected(final int pos) {
        ... // your hidden code
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mSpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

The new thread stuff isnt needed.

Comment: Even without the thread, the result is the same. If I removes the notify, the viewpager scrolls fluid.